# Finding out which days are weekends in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of birthdays in a google spreadsheet that I am working with. I am trying to find out all the days that would fall on a weekend, so that they can be read out on the Friday before.  I am comparing my current list of birthdays using this query:

```
=QUERY(B2:D430;"select * where month(B) = "&(MONTH(E2)-1)&" and day(B) = "&DAY(E2))
```

To my current date

```
=Today()
```

This compares just the month and day to the current one, and lets me get the ones for each day.  I have it set up in the month/day/year format.  How can I search the spreadsheet on Fridays for values that would fall on the weekend, so that I can get a listing of those values?

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: In my mind, the Today() part was a way to reference the date of birth against the current date. For example, if the value in the cell was 5/31/xxxx or 6/1/xxxx then they would be flagged on 5/30/2014 as being on the weekend.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.  I guess I could have explained it a little clearer

Comment: I gave that I try, and I am getting a Parse error.  I changed what you gave me slightly, as my data resides in column B.  Any idea why I might be getting that error?

Comment: If I shared it with you, would you be willing to look at it?

Comment: Hi.  This is the link [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvTDsiXiXUyqdHZzakg4QjF6T3EtVEJOU01sVV9jUUE&usp=sharing) It is the birthday spreadsheet and what I would like is for the formula to check the current date (Month/Day), and if it is a friday, find any values in columns C and D for the next two days.  I would then put this in another part of the spreadsheet so that I can pull the data into a section on a google doc template.  Paul

Comment: I tried that, and received #ERROR! all down the column.  Did you get that as well?

Comment: I unfortunately can't seem to get it to work.  Is there a way to QUERY in information?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how I would do this in the context of this particular spreadsheet since I can't see it, but the [WEEKNUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949?hl=en) and [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en) functions would be sufficient to identify if a birthday has happened on the same week as Today(), and additionally, to identify if Today() is Friday.